# Veutify calendar throws a timestamp error

Tags: vue.js, date, vuetify.js

I am getting the following error when I loading a Vuetify calendar.

```
vue.runtime.esm.js?c320:3019 Error: 2022-09-14  is not a valid timestamp. It must be a Date, number of milliseconds since Epoch, or a string in the format of YYYY-MM-DD or YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm. Zero-padding is optional and seconds are ignored.
```

Here is an excerpt of the code where the date is being set:

```js
const scheduleDate = new Date(fD['scheduleDate']).toISOString().slice(0,10)

console.log('DATE [calendar.ts] -> ', scheduleDate) // the date logs YYYY-MM-DD here
const start = scheduleDate + ' ' + fD['startTime']
console.log('START [calendar.ts] -> ', start) // also logs ok
```

In the calendar event object:

```js
const event = {
  color: color,
  name: 'meeting',
  date: scheduleDate,
  start: start,
}
```

I am not sure why this error is being thrown because the date appears to be in the correct format. Any guidance much appreciated.

Comment: can you give more precise logging.  what are the actual values of both `scheduleDate` and `start`?  The error can be from the `start` timestamp being wrong and would match the error log if `fD['startTime']` turned out to be empty string

Comment: if `scheduleDate` is not a String in the format `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm` then this may be causing the error. Strip the seconds off the string - or simply use a **Date** object instead.

Comment: The error was thrown because the event following the date in the error log didn't have any date at all. I added the date that was missing and it fixed it. But the error is confusing.